# Gunicorn + jwilder ~ 503 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, basic-authentication, jwilder-nginx-proxy

My working code is flask + jwilder(nginx) with basic auth, buth when i'm using gunicorn + jwilder(nginx) i'm got error..

My detail code in :
https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/1253

Thanks for help..